# C# Multiple Inheritance with Interfaces

Tags: c#, asp.net, multiple-inheritance

```
public interface IA
{
  void DoSomething();
  void Calculate();

}

public interface IB
{
  void DoSomethingElse();
  void Calculate();
}

public class A : IA
{
  void DoSomething() { }
  void Calculate() {}
}

public class B : IB
{
  void DoSomethingElse() { }
  void Calculate() {}
}

public class C : IA, IB
{

    //How can I implement Calculate() in class B and DoSomething() in class A?
}
```

How can I avoid duplicate code in class C.  Reference: [How to simulate multiple inheritance in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3199956/how-to-simulate-multiple-inheritance-in-c-sharp).  I don't want to write the full methods again in class C. Thanks for any help.

Comment: But you're not "writing the full methods again".  You're clearly using delegation and passing off the implementation to your embedded instances of `A` and `B`.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Sorry maybe I worded it incorrectly.  In class C, instead of "public void DoSomething(){m_A.DoSomething();}" I would like to use type cast if possible

Comment: @KevenDiuliy [Type cast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx)? How would you want to use type casting? I think you must mean something else.

Comment: I think that in your sample class `C` you'll need to explicitly implement both `IA.Calculate()` and `IB.Calculate()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `IA.Calculate()` is not the same as `IB.Calculate()` and you therefore can't just make `IB` inherit from `IA`, you can implement both interfaces in `C` by delegating execution on private instances of `A` and `B`:

```
public class C : IA, IB
{
    private A _a;
    private B _b;

    public C()
    {
        this._a = new A();
        this._b = new B();
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        this._a.DoSomething();
    }
    void IA.Calculate()
    {
        this._a.Calculate();
    }
    public void DoSomethingElse()
    {
        this._b.DoSomethingElse();
    }
    void IB.Calculate()
    {
        this._b.Calculate();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the response, when I tried to compile this it says "the exe does not contain a static "Main" method suitable for an entry point". Would that need to be added here? thanks again

Comment: This is just definition of class `C`, much like you defined it in your question. The rest of the code (other classes/interfaces definitions, Main method, etc.) are just as you had it in your question

Answer (score 1):

Note that you are not achieving multiple inheritance at all. C# has singular inheritance. You are implementing multiple interfaces.

There is absolutely no reason why you cannot implement the interfaces in classes `A` and `B`, and then have `B` derive from `A` and `C` derive from B. The method implementations from the interfaces can even be abstract, which forces the child class to do the implementation. If you follow this approach then you can still pass `C` around as `IA` or `IB` simply by casting or using the `as` keyword.

You can also have interface `IB` "inherit"<sup>1</sup> (implement) `IA`, which means anything that implements `IB` must also implement `IA`.

<sup>1</sup> When `IB` derives from `IA` it isn't inheritance like it is at the class level, it is actually **still** implementation. So `IB` **implements** `IA`, it doesn't inherit it.