# Inheriting from a superclass that already has subclasses

Tags: c#, inheritance

I've ran into the following design issue in my code and could use some pointers. I may be missing something obvious, or maybe I should be using some sort of a pattern that I'm not familiar with.

My inheritance tree looks like the following....

[image: Inheritance tree]

Projects A and B represent separate projects in Visual Studio. Other projects may also inherit from the classes in Project A.

A need has arisen to change/override some behaviour on `Control` in `SepaControl`, and have the other elements in that project, e.g. `SepaTextField` inherit from `SepaControl`.

I've highlighted the problem down the right hand side. I can't have `SepaTextField` inherit from `SepaControl` as `SepaTextField` already inherits from `TextField` which inherits from `Control`.

I could copy the code in `TextField` and add it to `SepaTextField` (with any additional modifications I need) and have that inherit from `SepaControl` but this seems very inefficient.

How might I restructure this better so I could modify the behaviour of my `Control` class without running into this problem?

(N.B having both `Control -> TextField -> SepaTextField` and `SepaControl -> TextField -> SepaTextField` is just for illustrative purposes. I would be looking for a single implementation of `SepaTextField`)

Thanks,

Comment: Since C# don't let you inherit from multiple classes you couldimplement multiple interfaces. I think the pattern you are looking for is called "composition over inheritance".

Comment: In this case f.e `SepaTextField` implements `ITextField` and `ISepaControl`.  `SepaTextField` needs then instances of `TextField` and `SepaControl`(passed f.e. via constructor) and the interface implementations use the instances.

Comment: Sorry Tim I don't follow. I don't understand 'Interface implementations use the instances'. If I implement `ITextField` and `ISepaControl` in `SepaTextField` don't I have to provide an implementation? How can that implementation come from instances passed in via the constructor?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3199977/284240

Comment: Your question is way too broad. Design questions like this are not a good fit for Stack Overflow, as they involve a healthy dose of opinion, and involve a wide variety of possible, different solutions. Even when a question offers some constraints, such questions are too broad, and your question offers none. While there are a number of answers showing how to address in C# what would otherwise be a multiple-inheritance design, it's not even clear that here MI would help.